# How to set alarm in BB10

Tags: blackberry-10, alarm, blackberry-cascades

Hi I am developing an application to set alarm in Blackberry 10 cascades. I have searched a lot and i found setting Remainder. But I want to set Alarm and an mp3 file as Alarm tone. Is there any way to this in Blackberry 10 using Cascades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. There is no API to programatically set the user's alarm.

However, you can invoke the clock application to a specific view-state (alarm screen) and allow the user to set the alarm themselves.

Here's how to invoke an app:
https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/sending_invocation.html

Here's the info on how to invoke the alarm clock:
https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/clock.html